# asp.net mvc linq sql problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, auto-increment, tinyint

I am working on a project using asp.net mvc 2 and linq to sql. The problem occurs when trying to insert data into a table where the table has an identity column type of tinyint. When trying to insert the following error occurs:

```
The primary key column of type 'TinyInt' cannot be generated by the server.
```

Does linq to sql support tinyint datatype?

Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I have been able to gather, Linq To Sql doesn't support TinyInt for auto increment fields.

Can you change the datatype to smallint or int?

See the following thread on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/402060/accessing-a-primary-key-id-when-its-declared-as-a-tinyint-using-linq):

> When you have a table with an identity
> field of tinyint and it's set to auto
> increment, you can't add a new record
> to that table. LINQ says, 'The primary
> key column of type 'TinyInt' cannot be
> generated by the server'
>
> Thank you for taking the time to send
> this feedback and bug report. We have
> reviewed the issue and confirmed the
> behavior, but we will not be fixing
> this in the next release of LINQ to
> SQL.

Comment: Thanks for your replay,it is a client projects so i dont know whether he is ready to change the datatype.Instead of linq to sql can i use anyother method like entity framework or nhibernate,which one is the best.please help me