# Disable CAST AS to optimize query in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, entity-framework

I'm using *Entity Framework 5* and I want to select data from *Oracle 10g* database.
Problem is that the database table is huge and the query generated by *Entity Framework* is ineffective. I want to get rid of those `CAST( [column] AS [type] )`. Is there any setting to turn them off?

C# code:

```
var context = new APPDB();
var q = context.APP_TABLE.Where(i => i.ID == 123);

// This is how I did get the generated SQL query
var str = ((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery) q ).ToTraceString();
```

The generated query:

```
SELECT 
 CAST( "Extent1"."ID" AS number(10,0)) AS "C1", 
"Extent1"."DESCRIPTION" AS "DESCRIPTION"
FROM "APP"."APP_TABLE" "Extent1"
WHERE (123 = ( CAST( "Extent1"."ID" AS number(10,0))))
```

What I want is the code to generate better performing query:

```
SELECT 
"Extent1"."ID" AS "C1", 
"Extent1"."DESCRIPTION" AS "DESCRIPTION"
FROM "APP"."APP_TABLE" "Extent1"
WHERE
"Extent1"."ID" = 123
```

Comment: What is the data type of `APP_TABLE.ID`?

Comment: @DavidG ```NUMBER(10,0)``` of course. :)

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016265/generated-query-for-tinyint-column-introduces-a-cast-to-int and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149456/entity-framework-ridiculous-query-casting-smallint-to-int-for-comparison

Comment: @Colin Yeah, I guess there is no other way... I think it's time to check out Dapper then. :D

Comment: @Taai Did you find the solution? I want to disable all "auto casting" like you, I don't want to specify all my column types manually

Answer (score 3):

Better later than never )

If you are using code first and manual mapping classes, use HasColumnType("INT") configuration for int properties.

For example:

```
var entity = builder.Entity<APP_TABLE>();

entity
    .HasKey(x => x.ID)
    .ToTable("APP_TABLE", "SCHEMA");

entity
    .Property(x => x.ID)
    .HasColumnType("INT");
```

Comment: And if I use DB first?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when using (short?) on the database and in an object property to perform the IQyueryable.

When using Equal() it usually do some bugs in code. When using the simple comparision, the T-SQL send an CAST() in two sides of the query. The bad thing: when using CAST in Transact SQL, Oracle does not use the INDEXES, making a simple select that runs in miliseconds direct in the database taking an eternity when running this way

Using this approach, the TSQL is transformed without the cast as an OR, that is less painfull than using the CAST. In case of using non nullable fields, the or does not appear, making the performance very high

In some cases, using Equal() gets rid of the cast conversion, but it not seems to work with short?

Lambda:

```
if (filter.Property.HasValue)
    query = query.Where(w => new short?[] { 
filter.Property}.Contains(w.Property));
```

SQL sent to Oracle:

```
WHERE (("Extent1"."Property" = :p__linq__0) OR (("Extent1"."Property" IS NULL) AND (:p__linq__0 IS NULL)))
```